# How do i get the object name of an element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

im playing around with a plugin i found on the internet in creating a shopping cart, the plugin(jquery code) code im pretty sure refers to my '#featured' div tag in my html however im not 100% sure. Anyway this my html where i call the smartcart plugin

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Call Smart Cart instead of features maybe something more higher up to include more features      
    $('#featured').smartCart();
    });
</script>
<div id="featured"></div>
```

this is a snippit of the plugin im playing with

```
(function( $ ){

$.fn.smartCart =function() {
var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.smartCart.defaults, options);
return this.each(function() {

            var obj = $(this);
            alert(obj); 
};
})( jQuery );
```

the code in question is where it says var obj=$(this), the alert brings back 'object object', ive tried attr('name') and .selector and prop.('name') and they either brought back blank or "undefined". Could someone please tell me im right in thinking that 'this' is referring to my featured div thats in my html and also why when i try and get its name back from the alert it doesn't work. just either object object or undefined

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger such as firebug?

Comment: It showed `undefined` because the `div` doesn't have a `name`, but an `id`, try `.attr('id');`

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A set attribute from the element the plugin was used on or some information to indicate what type of object is returned?

Comment: If you want the `id` then please *don't* use `$(this).attr('id')`, just use `this.id`. Or, given that this will return `undefined` if an `id` doesn't exist, you might want to use `var variableName = this.id || '';` to return an empty string.

Comment: I simply wanted to confirm that using the keyword this was refering to my div element, at the time i couldnt see my fault @BobKruithof and i tried firbug, i think mine maybe currupted everytime i inspect element my browser freezes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div` doesn't have the `name` attribute, that's why it's `undefined`.

**Also, you're missing a closing `})` on the third from last line**.

To answer your comment on whether `this` refers to the `div` element, the answer is **yes**. There is no need to wrap it into a jQuery object again (it already is one).

First add it:

```
<div id="featured" name="foo"></div>
```

Then do:

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.smartCart =function() {
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.smartCart.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {

            var obj = $(this);
            alert(obj.attr("name")); 
        }); //you were missing this
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: @BobKruithof I'm pretty sure it was, without those missing brackets it would have **never** worked.

Comment: The missing brackets would obviously be a problem. Anyway, OP explained he wanted to be sure the keyword `this` represented the element he used the plugin on.

Comment: @BobKruithof I've added that to my answer.